# Iphone 14( ios 16 ) home screen app, new window link

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, ios16

My scenario:

open website in Safari,
add it to home screen.
open it from home screen
at some place  in website - there is   link which opens in  new tab  ( target=_blank )

on Iphone 13 an prior  there is top panel  with Done button which allow to close it and return to main page.

[image]

on Iphone  14  doing same steps - but panel with Done  missed.   and no way to close window and back to main page. My users literally stuck on new page without ability to return
[image]

Is something in manifest required?